# How to put same entities in EhCache from different methods

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, caching, ehcache

I have three methods:

@Cacheable
getCompany(Long id);

@Cacheable
getCompany(String code);

@Cacheable
getCompanies();

They're using same cache from EhCache, when I call first getCompanies() (and all companies are loaded into cache) and next I call getCompany by id, this method returns company object not from cache but directly from DB (and also put the object to cache, but with different key - so we have now TWO same objects in one cache).
How can I implement custom key generator to force all methods to put/read from cache?

Answer (score 0):

**Overloaded `getCompany()`:**

The cache is a lookup by key. As you have two methods with different key types, the cache has no mapping for the other type of key. You can use double caching aka put each company into the cache twice using two keys. Spring offers the more general `@Caching` annotation for more complex rules:

```
@Caching(cacheable = @Cacheable(key = "#code"), put = {@CachePut(key = "#result.id"), @CachePut(key = "#result.code")})
getCompany(String code) {
}

@Caching(cacheable = @Cacheable(key = "#id"), put = {@CachePut(key = "#result.id"), @CachePut(key = "#result.code")})
getCompany(Long id) {
}
```

**`getCompanies()`:**

This list all kind method has no parameters and therefore uses always a general key to access the cache. The result is also a different type than the other methods so the cache has no chance to determine what to return for the first time.

It will always return the same companies from the second call on!

Even if you would enforce the cache somehow to return all companies cached, it would typically not what you want as the cache changes (TTL, etc.) over time even without changing the companies in the backing system (database, e.g.).

If you really want to use this and you have control over the only code manipulation the backing system, have a look at `@CacheEvict` to make sure cleaning up the cache when changing companies.